# Excel: Name Table after Import from CSV - running into issues

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have been working on a workbook for some reporting functions.

I have just been getting back into VB and a bit rusty - in front of me also sits a 1000+ page book and have been all over sites like this. It seems that i can get close - however end up just a bit off.

Every week I have new data coming in, that I will be using to update some pivot tables and so on.   I have 5 areas where data will be imported and currently have the import functioning, however I run into issues with two areas: I can't seem to have it create a table of the data that was just imported & I have no error checking. I need the tables named so i can use the date throughout the worksheet.

Any guidance would be great for the following:

- How can I simply clear out the current table at A2 and import the new data not to have to rename the table and the headers? (my imported data comes in as "First Name" not First_Name" so would be nice to just keep it in this format.
- How do I add error checking on this to say if someone runs it and closes the window that it will not clear the worksheet and launch a debugger?

Here is what i have working (I have tried many things but back to this)

```
Sub ImportMaster() 
' this is the master list of all NA accounts for ..... 
' NA_ACCOUNTS_LIST Worksheet 
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NA_Accounts_List") ws.UsedRange.Clear strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please selec text file...") With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, _ Destination:=ws.Range("A2"))
        .Name = "ProgramData"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False End With '  ws.Name = "testing"

    ' updates the date Range("C12").ClearContents Range("C12") = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")


    ' This will focus this worksheet after upate Sheets("NA_Accounts_List").Visible = xlSheetVisible Sheets("NA_Accounts_List").Select


    MsgBox "Imported data successfully!"

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

let me see if i understood, what you want is clear cell A2 from the current table that you are working? and insert a new data at the same cell?

Comment: You know - out of all of the posts i looked at i left out the most basic of my request ... sorry about that.

Comment: I have a worksheet that i use for raw data.   its the imported data for that CSV file and the column width will always remain the same (BK) however the row count will change.   I need to import the data with the table starting at "A2" and over to "BK2" then down depending on CSV file rows.  

So, the import needs to clear out the data in the table that states at A2, import the new data & keep the formatting the same for the table. 

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have lucky, i guess its should solve.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        ex.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wk = ex.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wk.Worksheets[1]; // set the first worksheet
        DataTable dtb = mysql.mysql_data_adapter(); // the data that are coming from mysql
        DataRow row;

        for (int i = 0; i < dtb.Columns.Count; i++) // add header
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rg = (ws.Cells[1, i + 1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range); // excel start in 1
            rg.Value2 = dtb.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < dtb.Rows.Count + 2; i++) // add data without change header, and this for run the row
        {
            row = dtb.Rows[i - 2]; //  where to start at correct row, dont oforget, start in 2 because 1 are the header
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 < dtb.Columns.Count + 1; i2++) // where run the collumns
            {
                try
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rg = (ws.Cells[i, i2] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range); 
                    rg.Value2 = row[i2 - 1].ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dietrich, 

This looks to be using a MySQL Adapter ... ?? .. I am importing right from a CSV file on the local machine.

Comment: dont have difference how you get the data, transfer the CSV file to a datatable and use 'for' to run the rows and columns.

Comment: I am not following - from the code i provided for the sub, how do i use this?

Comment: well, you need convert the data .csv to datatable object, follow this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429712/Convert-CSV-File-to-data-table

after you do it, you can do everything without any problem.